# jquery pagination not working with dynamic table

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a table as follows:

```
<table id="user_logs_table" border="2" class="paginated">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%">Log Date</th>
                        <th width="15%">Log Time</th>
                        <th width="70%">Description</th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                {{for row in user_log[:19]:}}
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%">{{=row['log_date']}}</td>
                        <td width="15%">{{=row['log_time']}}</td>
                        <td width="70%">{{=row['description']}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                {{pass}}
            </table>
```

The table has filters, and when the filter is applied, I call the following function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{=URL('users', 'show_user_log', args=[reqarg])}}",
    data: {date_from: datefrom, date_to: dateto, time_from: timefrom, time_to: timeto},
    success: function(data) {
        result = "<thead><tr> <th width='15%'>Log Date</th> <th width='15%'>Log Time</th> <th width='70%''>Description</th> </tr></thead><tbody>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>"
            result += "<td>" + data[i]['log_date'] + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + data[i]['log_time'] + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + data[i]['description'] + "</td>";
            result += "</tr>"
        }
        result +="</tbody>"
        document.getElementById('user_logs_table').innerHTML = result;
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

But the result of this is that the rows get added to the table even though my pagination script only allows 10 results per page. Why is this happening?

EDIT(clarification): When the page loads initially, the table shows the last 20 activities done by the user across 2 pages. The total log contains ~1000 items per user stored in a json file.

When I apply the filter, the url: "{{=URL('users', 'show_user_log', args=[reqarg])}}", function retrieves the correct activities to be displayed.

If I am on the first page of my table and apply the filter, and the filter returns 100 results, the first page will contain 90 of the results and 10 on the next page. If I am on the second page of the table and apply the filter, the second page has 90 results and the first page has 10.

All the rows displayed in the table are correct and reflect what I have entered in the filter.

Comment: You're not being clear.  What do you mean by, "But the result of this is that the rows get added to the table even though my pagination script only allows 10 result per page."  Do you mean to say this: "But all rows, even if more than 10, get added to the table even though my pagination script only allws 10 results per page."?

Comment: More or less yes. I added the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I have solved it in this way:

```
 var table = $('#sample_2').DataTable();
                     for (var i = 1; i < dataInfo.length; i = i + 8) {

                                var dataid = dataInfo[i];
                                var schoolid = dataInfo[i+1];
                                var schoolname = dataInfo[i+2];
                                var address = dataInfo[i+3];
                                var createdat = dataInfo[i+4];
                                var displayname = dataInfo[i+5];
                                var shortname = dataInfo[i + 6];
                                var status = dataInfo[i + 7];
                        // console.log(dataInfo[i]);\
                         var startdeadbolt = "#{deadbolt.externalizedRestriction externalRestrictions:['Edit Data']}";
                         var frst =  startdeadbolt + "<a class='btn btn-mini details' id='" + dataid + "'  href='/datamanagement/dataDetails/"+dataid+"'>Details</a>";
                         var lastdeadbolt = "#{/deadbolt.externalizedRestriction}";
                         var last = lastdeadbolt + "<a class='btn btn-mini btn-danger delete_data' id='" + dataid + "'><i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i> Delete</a>";
                         table.row.add([
                             dataid,
                             schoolid,
                             schoolname,
                             address,
                             createdat,
                             displayname,
                             shortname,
                             status,
                             frst,
                             last
                         ]).draw();
```